# boost thread compiler error with GCC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost, conditional-statements

on linux, gcc 4.3, compiling a class with boost::thread implementation and mutexes / condition variables I get the following strange error, apparently due to type conflicts with the posix thread library:

```
*Compiling: filter.cpp
/usr/include/boost/thread/condition.hpp: In member function »void boost::condition::wait(L&) [with L = boost::mutex]«:
/host/.../filter.cpp:68:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/thread/condition.hpp:90: Error: no match für »operator!« in »!lock«*
*/usr/include/boost/thread/condition.hpp:90: Notice: candidates are: operator!(bool) <built in>*
*/usr/include/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:66: Error: »pthread_mutex_t boost::mutex::m_mutex« is private
/usr/include/boost/thread/condition.hpp:93: Error: in this context*
```

The code is:

```
void CFilter::process( CData **s )
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock bufferLock(m_mutex);
    while (!m_bStop)
        m_change.wait(bufferLock);                      //<- line 68

    // ... further processing
}
```

with the class declaration

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

class CFilter
{
    // ...
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> m_thread;
    boost::mutex m_mutex;
    boost::condition m_change;
    // ...

    process( CData **s );
}
```

The operator error takes place in boost's condition.hpp, in

```
if (!lock)
    throw lock_error();
```

I'm using Boost 1.38.0, on Windows I don't find any problems. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wait on the `bufferLock`, not `m_mutex`:

```
while (!m_bStop)
    m_change.wait(bufferLock);
```

[Condition<>::wait()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/boost/condition.html) takes a [`ScopedLock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/thread/concepts.html#thread.concepts.ScopedLock) as parameter, not a [`Mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/thread/concepts.html#thread.concepts.Mutex).

Comment: That's right, but it does not solve the problem, the compiler error remains